# Maven clean install COMPILATION ERROR cannot access jar, zip END header not found

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-plugin

When building my application on Jenkins using maven I am seeing the following error after running:

`mvn clean install -q -U -T 1.5C -DskipTests -Dsvn.info.skip=true`

**Error:**

> ** [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
>   [ERROR] error reading /apps/jenkins/workspace/some_branch/.m2/com.some_company/any_random.jar; zip file is empty 
>   [ERROR] cannot access com.some_company.some_class
>   cannot access cannot access com.some_company.some_class zip END header not found
>   cannot access jar

I tried excluding the dependency that was causing the issue as it was transitive but now it happens for other dependencies.

The dependencies are stored in nexus.

I have looked at the JDK being used to build the JARS and considered Network issues but nothing explains this.

Clearing Jenkins and the .m2 folder works sometime for one or two builds but I would like to find a better solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Delete the local repository and try again.

Comment: I have update my question. Only work for one or two builds. What would be causing this?

Comment: Your local cache is screwed up. You have to cleanup your cache and turn on checksum policy... Details https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/

Comment: Another possibility is multiple builds downloading the same jars simultaneously and one stepping on another.

Answer (score 35):

The JAR in your local Maven cache is corrupt.

Just delete the file

```
.m2/com.some_company/any_random.jar
```

and rerun your goal again.
Maybe your network or internet connection is slow or your hard disk need check.

Answer (score 1):

### Error reproduction

I've experienced the same error as soon as I've added a global variable at the beginning of a tag in the `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<url>${env.CI_PROJECT_URL}/api/v4/projects/000/packages/maven</url>
```

Just for a try, I added the `a` letter at the beginning, even if it doesn't resolve to an existing URL:

```xml
<url>a${env.CI_PROJECT_URL}/api/v4/projects/000/packages/maven</url>
```

And the compilation worked, but the publication could not due to the wrong URL.

### Solution

I've solved the error by just interpolating the domain of the server, while I manually wrote the protocol part as `https`:

```xml
<url>https://${env.CI_SERVER_HOST}/api/v4/projects/000/packages/maven</url>
```

In your case you may need to apply a similar modification in order to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Mohannd answer helped me knowing what was going on.

But, I was pulling the dependency from an internal repository, so the solution was accessing the internal repository and replacing the corrupted JAR file.

Go to your local repository (cache) and remove the JAR file.

After that run `mvn clean install -U` to download it again from the internal repository.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps -

1. Delete the target folder in intelliJ project.
2. Delete the .m2 folder wherever the maven dependency is downloaded at local machine.
3. Make sure your intelliJ maven setting is referring to correct setting.xml and correct maven repository in .m2 directory, If not correct then correct it.
4. Make sure you are connected to required VPN as per your organisation policy and also make sure you are connected to right required firewall to fetch latest dependency from nexus or hitHub repository.
5. Do invalidate Cache and restart your IntelliJ if not yet done. and select first two option from the pop up to clear the cache and other history.
6. Now after updating all your indexes in intelliJ run command mvn clean install -U from command promt or GUI of intelliJ.
7. Wait for  re download the jars and make sure no network interuption during this process.
   This way you may resolve your issue.